# How to calculate distance to other galaxies using type 1a supernova?

Tags: distances, supernova, python

This is for a project in astronomy with extensive data analysis. How should I calculate the distance of galaxies using AGN and supernova Ia? I am using the data from dr17 of SDSS.

Comment: What have you already tried? Type Ia have absolute magnitudes of -19.3, so you probably could use inverse square law given you have magnitude of the Ia in said galaxy.

Comment: @fasterthanlight But who ever has that information?

Answer (score 2):

The absolute peak magnitude of type 1a supernovae is to some degree correlated with the decay time of the supernova light curve. The [Phillips relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phillips_relationship) says that the peak absolute magnitude in the blue (B) region of the spectrum is

$$M=-21.726+2.698\cdot \Delta m$$

where $\Delta m$ is the observed decline of the B-magnitude 15 days after maximum.

With the observed apparent magnitude $m$ you have then the [distance modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_modulus) $m-M$ and thus the distance $d$

$$d=10^{1+(m-M)/5} \ \mathrm{Parsecs}$$