# How to obtain luminosity distance from a light curve

Tags: observational-astronomy, distances, supernova, light-curve

I have some light curve data of a SN Ia from which I want to find the luminosity distance $D_L$.

How can I do it mathematically?

I'll then try to implement the answer using Python.

Comment: The references here might be of help: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phillips_relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to basically assume that the supernova is a "standard candle," i.e., if we know with confidence how bright it $\it{should}$ be, then we can estimate the distance after measuring it's luminosity.

In a simple, crude approach, one can just use the good 'ole [luminosity formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity#Luminosity_formulae): assuming the source radiates with constant luminosity, its brightness will decrease with the inverse square law, and you invert the formula to get the luminosity distance,
$$ D_{\rm L} = \sqrt{\frac{L}{4\pi F}}$$
where $L$ is the luminosity and $F$ is the [flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_flux).

Here's a [GUI](http://astro.unl.edu/naap/distance/animations/snCurveExplorer.html) you may or may not find useful (ie see item 13 [here](https://www.physics.unlv.edu/%7Ejeffery/astro/applet/naap_supernovae.html)).

Lots of helpful info [here](https://www.physics.unlv.edu/%7Ejeffery/astro/applet/naap_supernovae.html), and they also have an applet that you can download and play around with which uses the [distance modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_modulus) (as answered [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/48365/how-to-calculate-distance-to-other-galaxies-using-type-1a-supernova)).

Note this is only a (crude) approximation, since it assumes zero extinction due to dust and doesn't account for cosmology. If this is for a research project, you'll likely need to do something more sophisticated and should consult your advisor and the literature, i.e., see [this](https://notebook.community/banneker-aztlan/python-week-2/Part%204/Supernova%20Cosmology) nice python notebook, or [this](https://github.com/sncosmo/sncosmo) python module.

I hope this helps!